# How to read multiple parameters from a URL

Tags: go

I have a reverse proxy API that reads the parameters of a localhost API call and then sends those parameters to a 3rd party API.

I'm able to get this working correctly if I only use one parameter. Like so:

`http://localhost:8080/path?page=1`

I want to be able to use more than one parameter however like so:

`http://localhost:8080/path?page=1&param=x`

Please see my code below:
This function catches an HTTP request and then sends those parameters to another API.

```
func (s *Server) getReverseProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // when I try to append another query in the list a long with page, I get an error 
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["page"]

    if !ok || len(keys[0]) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'page' is missing")
        return
    }

    // Query()["key"] will return an array of items,
    // we only want the single item.
    key := keys[0]

    log.Println("Url Param 'page' is: " + string(key))
    params := url.Values{
        "page[size]":   []string{"100"},
        "page[number]": []string{""},
    }
    u := &url.URL{
        Scheme:   "https",
        Host:     "url.com",
        Path:     "/path",
        RawQuery: params.Encode(),
    }
}
```

Without having to refractor, am I missing something simple here? How can I add another parameter for my function to catch?

Comment: `r.URL.Query()["param"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code below ...

```golang
keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["page"]
```

it returns the param value of `page`, but in `[]string` type. To retrieve more params, simply add similar statement with different param name. for example:

```
keysPage, ok := r.URL.Query()["page"]
keysParamA, ok := r.URL.Query()["ParamA"]
keysParamB, ok := r.URL.Query()["ParamB"]
keysParamC, ok := r.URL.Query()["ParamC"]
```

Or, you can also use the `r.URL.Query().Get(key)` to return the param value in `string` type.

```
page := r.URL.Query().Get("page")
paramA := r.URL.Query().Get("ParamA")
paramB := r.URL.Query().Get("ParamB")
paramC := r.URL.Query().Get("ParamC")
```

Answer (score 1):

`r.URL.Query()` returns a `map[string][]string`

you can do a

```
keys, ok := r.URL.Query()
//browse through keys by
keys["params"]
keys["page"]
```